# sparql rdf fuseki how can i filter date in graph name

Tags: rdf, sparql, fuseki

I got a lot of graph names on jena fuseki rdf store, 
These are the names of my graph:

```
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T04:27:57Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:20:59Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:22:29Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:25:03Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:27:01Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:30:37Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:44:02Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:52:19Z> |
| <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:58:47Z> |
```

and so on.
How can i filter the graphs to get all the graphs between two date?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier when we have actual data to work with.  Please be sure to provide data that we can work with in the future.  For this case, I've just bound the URIs with embedded date times to the **?dateUri** variable using a **values** block.  The comments in the query explain what's happening.  The general idea is to convert the URI to a string, strip off the common prefix, convert the suffix to a **xsd:dateTime**, and the filter based on it.

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?dateTime where {
  #-- the "dates" encoded in URIs
  values ?dateUri { <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T04:27:57Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:20:59Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:22:29Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:25:03Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:27:01Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:30:37Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:44:02Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:52:19Z>
                    <http://stormsmacs/tests/2015-03-03T05:58:47Z> }

  #-- an arbitrary begin and end date                    
  values ?begin { "2015-03-03T05:22:29Z"^^xsd:dateTime }
  values ?end   { "2015-03-03T05:44:02Z"^^xsd:dateTime }

  #-- extract the dateTime portion from the URI string, and convert
  #-- it to an xsd:dateTime.
  bind( xsd:dateTime(strafter(str(?dateUri),"http://stormsmacs/tests/")) as ?dateTime )

  #-- filter results based on the begin and end time
  filter( ?begin <= ?dateTime && ?dateTime <= ?end )
}
```

```
----------------------------------------
| dateTime                             |
========================================
| "2015-03-03T05:22:29Z"^^xsd:dateTime |
| "2015-03-03T05:25:03Z"^^xsd:dateTime |
| "2015-03-03T05:27:01Z"^^xsd:dateTime |
| "2015-03-03T05:30:37Z"^^xsd:dateTime |
| "2015-03-03T05:44:02Z"^^xsd:dateTime |
----------------------------------------
```